# List View for Custom Object Does Not Show Fields in its Header

Tags: lightninglistview

On one of my developer account, list view of **custom** **object** does not show Fields in Header. I have created a test object **DelTestObj**, which has fields **Name**, **Del1** and **Age**, which should have appeared on the table header of the list view. Can someone identify where my settings of the Org went wrong?
First Image Shows Account List View, which is fine.
[image: standard object list view]

Second Image Shows List View of Custom Object, missing fields in header
[image: custom object list view]

Contents inside Custom Object
[image: test contents inside]

The story is same with all custom objects.
OWD is Read/ Write for custom object
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just that they're not in the header, they're not in the rows of the List View either. The List View has a single column, which is `DelTestObj Name`.

The automatically provided Recently Viewed list view uses the fields defined on an object's Search Layout. Go to Setup > Object Manager > DelTestObj and then choose Search Layouts from the left sidebar. From the dropdown box at the right of the Default Layout, choose Edit, and then select the fields you want displayed in the Recently Viewed list view; these fields will also display in search results for the object. Click Save, and go back to your object's Recently Viewed list to see the results.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, The issue got resolved with your Reply. This problem occured to me on one of my dev account.
Thanks again